# Происхождение слова "хахаль"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Может, вопрос глупый, но каково происхождение слова "хахаль"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ХАХАЛЬ. Искон. Происхождение неясно. Обычно толкуется как суф. производное от хахать "смеяться". Однако иногда объясняется по-другому: как экспрессивное образование, родств. др.-чешск. chochánie "любовь", польск. kochać "любить".

Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь, 2004

И ещё:

Прилично или неприлично употребление того или иного слова русского языка, зависит от обстоятельств, в которых оно произносится.
Происхождение слова хахаль довольно безобидно. Считается, что у него два «источника» – с одной стороны, украинский глагол коха́ть, то есть «любить», а с другой – звукоподражание ха-ха. Вместе они и определили значение слова хахаль как «любовник, к которому нельзя относиться серьезно».
(http://lib.rus.ec/b/174940/read)

Answer (score 0):

Я против звукоподражательной весии. Звукоподражательность вообще малопродуктивна для таких слов. А вот украинское "Хохать" вкупе с со славянскими формами (видимо, родственными ему) - то что надо.

Answer (score 0):

"Хахаль "-ухажёр, поклонник, слово прост. Может, от "ха-ха", типа "всегда улыбающийся поклонник".

Answer (score 0):

*EkaterinaKashtanova4 пишет:*

> украинский глагол коха́ть, то есть
> «любить»

Если точнее, то "кохати". Такая версия вызывает некоторые сомнения. Звуки "к" и "х" в украинском языке совершенно разные. Украинское мягкое "г" ещё можно путать с "х". Но в том же украинском "г" **никогда** не смешивается с "к".

Comment: Здесь речь идет не о путанице, а об регрессивной ассимиляции.
Превый согласный при заимствовании уподобился последующему.  
Сомнение вызывает скорее суффикс -ль, подобного которому в русском нет.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это древняя морфема, которая сохранилась в "составных" суффиксах: льщик/льщица (плате**льщик**, ныря**льщик**, пряди**льщиц**а), льн (спа**льн**ый, вяза**льн**ый). То есть говорить, что его в русском нет, нельзя, мне кажется.